# Where do I find pyomo classes, methods and properties?

Tags: pyomo

I need a documentation about classes, methods and properties of Pyomo. Where do I find that. I have been looking for this dicumentation for some days.

Silvana Nobre

Answer (score 0):

You can use
dir([object])¶
Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

```
m = AbstractModel()

print (dir(m))
```

will print all properties of the AbstractModel object